# How can i post json and image at the same time? Vuetify + axios

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

**I got the data with json format but also got image in same form. How can I post the image and json data to laravel request at the same time?**

Data Object:

```js
{
  "pwra_uuid": "",
  "purchase_order_uuid": "26729191407884625",
  "group_tasks_uuid": "26729191407884553",
  "pwra_code": "HIS-CPPS-00281",
  "pwra_dt": "2020-08-25",
  "time": "05:25",
  "task_name": "fdsafdsa",
  "specific_location": "fdsafdsa",
  "time_session": "AM",
  "status": "",
  "employees": [
    "26535933801136175",
    "26535933801136183",
    "26535933801136169"
  ]
}
```

Vue js code:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            chosenFile: null,
            pwra: [],
        };
    },
    methods: {
        create() {
            let data = this.pwra;
            formData.append("image", this.chosenFile);
            formData.append("data", data);
            console.log(data);
            axios.post("/pwra", formData, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                },
            });
        },
    },
};
```

Laravel Code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $requestData = $request->all();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your complex data object (complex meaning it's not just a flat key / value map), your best bet is to stringify it as JSON and have your server-side code parse it to an array.

For example

```js
formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));
```

and on the server-side, something like this

```php
$data = json_decode($request->input('data'));
```